query params regex to requests.get
query_params = { "key": "abc*"}
requests.get(url, params=query_params)

I want to use regex in query params for requests.get function in python,
It should return all the keys for which value starts with the string 'abc'
How can this be done ?
I tried this but it does not treat * as a regex, instead it treats it as a normal character

Sounds like the endpoint you're sending the request to doesn't support regular expressions. Consult the API documentation for an alternate solution.

The string starts with abc; for this the regex would be ^abc. Your abc* looks for "ab", "abc", "abcccccc",....
